# .htaccess Redirect to a Parameter in the URL

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to allow for users to promote my affiliate product using Clickbank.  Clickbank only supports for an affiilate link to link directly to the homepage of a product.

For instance, an example clickbank affiliate link might look like:

http://example.hop.clickbank.net/ which would take you directly to the homepage of the product you're promoting with the final URL you land on looking something like:

http://exampleproduct.com/?hop=MyAffiliateID

However, you can pass parameters in the original hoplink like this:

http://example.hop.clickbank.net/?page=specific-page

If you visit that link, the final URL you land on looks like this:

http://exampleproduct.com/?hop=MyAffiliateID&page=specific-page

What I need to do, is if the "page" parameter is set, to redirect to the "page" parameter (and if the "page" parameter isn't set, to do nothing).

Using the above example, I would need the htaccess file to redirect this URL:

ttp://exampleproduct.com/?hop=MyAffiliateID&page=specific-page

To this URL:

http://exampleproduct.com/specific-page?hop=MyAffiliateID

I know it's typically proper etiquette to include what I have so far in regard to working on this, but to be perfectly honest, I don't even have a clue as to where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, I just needed some simple PHP to accomplish this, no .htaccess required.

This is what I'm using to get the above accomplished:

```
$page = $_GET["page"];
$hop = $_GET["hop"];
if (isset($url)) {
header("Location: " . $page . "?hop=" . $hop);
exit;
}
```